# Adding custom options in to cart through API in magento2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, magento-2.0, rest-api

I have custom options like **'booking_from'** and **'booking_till'** in my custom module, everything works in the backend is fine. But how can I add those options in a cart through REST API in magento2.1.7? Or did I need to create custom extension_attributes for those options .? Hope some experts will here to clear this.